# Disable form element if user click different button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have this 2 button which is link to the same modal form. This is the form.

```
<form name="addUser" ng-submit="(addUser.$valid) ? add() : '';">

    <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
     <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
       <input class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required>
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
                </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.name.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
      <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
       <input class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required>
         <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.name.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
                </div>

     <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';" ng-hide="hideField">
      <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required ng-minlength="5">
         <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
                </div>

     <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';" ng-hide="hideField">
       <label class="control-label" for="confirmpassword">Re-enter Password</label>
         <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" ng-model="user.confirmpassword" required ng-minlength="5">
           <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
                </div>
```

this is the button.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addUser()">Add New User</button>
    </div>
```

what i want is that when user click this button (below) Password and confirm password in the form will not appear.

```
<a ng-click="addUser(user)" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
```

How can i disable that element?

this is js code

```
$scope.addUser = function(user) {
        $dialog.open({
            showClose: false,
            closeByEscape: true,
            template: 'views/user/user-user-add.html',
            controller: ['$scope', function ($dialogScope) {
                $dialogScope.isLoading =false;
                $dialogScope.title = "New User";
                $dialogScope.user = {
                    username : "" ,
                    name : "",
                    password :"",
                    confirmpassword :"",
                    status : "",
                    scope : {},
                };
                if(user){
                    $dialogScope.title = "Update User";
                    $scope.hideField = true;
                    $dialogScope.user = {
                        username :user.username ,
                        name :user.name ,
                        password :user.password,
                        confirmpassword:user.confirmpassword,
                        status : user.status,
                        scope : user.scope,
                    };
                }

                $dialogScope.add = function() {
                    $scope.users.push($dialogScope.user);
                    $dialogScope.closeThisDialog();
                }
            }],
        });
    };
```

Comment: do you have any js code ?

Comment: @HiteshDabhi edited as above

Comment: do you want to hide password and confirm password field when i click on the a tag?

Comment: Have the button set a scope property and wrap the form inputs in `ng-hide` directives, eg `ng-click="addUser(user); hideFields = true"` and `<div ng-hide="hideFields" class="form-group..."`

Comment: i want to hide the whole thing about password and confirm password if i click another button (now i am using the same form for 2 button) @Batman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module("stack", [])
    .controller("move", function($scope) {
        $scope.user = {
            username: '',
            name: '',
            password: '',
            confirmpassword: ''
        };
        // this.apps = features;
        $scope.add = function(user) {
            $scope.hideField = true;
        }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="stack">

<head>
    <title>stack</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="loadingoverlay.js"></script> -->
    <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="move">
    <form name="addUser">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
            <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required>
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.name.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required>
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.name.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';" ng-hide="hideField">
            <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required ng-minlength="5">
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';" ng-hide="hideField">
            <label class="control-label" for="confirmpassword">Re-enter Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" ng-model="user.confirmpassword" required ng-minlength="5">
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addUser()">Add New User</button>
        </div>
        <a ng-click="add(user)" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

do you need this?@Sue

Comment: yes exactly like this. but why mine is still showing password and confirm password. i edited the code above

Comment: js part and also i add ng-hide

Comment: i have called two different functions for two buttons.

Comment: but i want to use the same function for both button.

Comment: i have checked it.you have to use a different function name (anything other than addUser).I think it will work.

Comment: but if i use different function name the modal form will not open because those two button link to the same modal form. the only different is the content. that is why i want to disable password and confirm password.

Comment: then you have to change the following name-->
ng-class="addUser" --> ng-class="other_name". i think it will work.please let me know after checking.

Comment: its working now. i just add $dialogScope.hideField = true, since the form is in modal, so need to add dialog. thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

add an `ng-disabled` attribute to your `element` to be `disabled` and set it on `click` of `button/anchor`

```
<input type='text' placeholder='will get disabledd' ng-disabled="disable">
<a ng-click="disable=true" class="btn"><i>DISABLE DD</i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run this snippet of `ng-disabled` I've edited form @Batman. It disabled the password fields on edit `ng-click`

```js
angular.module("stack", [])
    .controller("move", function($scope) {
        $scope.user = {
            username: '',
            name: '',
            password: '',
            confirmpassword: ''
        };
        // this.apps = features;
        $scope.add = function(user) {
            $scope.hideField = true;
        }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="stack">

<head>
    <title>stack</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="loadingoverlay.js"></script> -->
    <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="move">
    <form name="addUser">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
            <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required>
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.name.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required>
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.name.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
            <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required ng-minlength="5" ng-disabled="hideField">
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';" >
            <label class="control-label" for="confirmpassword">Re-enter Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-disabled="hideField" name="confirmpassword" ng-model="user.confirmpassword" required ng-minlength="5">
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addUser()">Add New User</button>
        </div>
        <a ng-click="add(user)" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps.